# Filling a new column with cummax and cummin values with condition on a rolling interval

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame in which I want to populate two columns of rolling cumulative max and cumulative min values for intervals between 2 conditions:

Example: I want to find cumulative max and min values for rows between A and B in the Column "Condition". If the row is outside this condition, we ignore it.

Example of desired output:

| Condition | Value | Cummax | Cummin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | -1 | -1 | -1 |
|  | 2 | 2 | -1 |
|  | 3 | 3 | -1 |
| B | 1 | 3 | -1 |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
|  | 1 | 1 | 1 |
|  | -1 | 1 | -1 |
| B | 1 | 1 | -1 |
|  | 3 |  |  |
| A | 2 | 2 | 2 |
|  | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| B | -2 | 2 | -2 |

I have tried using:

```
df.loc[(df['Condition'].ffill()=="A")|(df['Condition']=="B"), "Cummax"] = df["Value"].cummax()
```

However, this will grab the overall cumulative maximum value up to that point. Appreciate any advice on resolving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option :

```
ff = df["Condition"].ffill()
unwanted_bs = ff.eq("B") & ff.eq(ff.shift())

blocks = ((tmp:=ff.mask(unwanted_bs))
          .loc[tmp.eq("B")].groupby(tmp).cumcount()
          .reindex_like(ff).bfill().mask(unwanted_bs))

out = (df.join(df["Value"].groupby(blocks)
         .agg(["cummax", "cummin"])
         .rename(str.title, axis=1))
         .convert_dtypes())
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   Condition  Value  Cummax  Cummin
0          A     -1      -1      -1
1       <NA>      2       2      -1
2       <NA>      3       3      -1
3          B      1       3      -1
4          A      1       1       1
5       <NA>      1       1       1
6       <NA>     -1       1      -1
7          B      1       1      -1
8       <NA>      3    <NA>    <NA>
9          A      2       2       2
10      <NA>      1       2       1
11         B     -2       2      -2
```

Visualization of the blocks (*with the [Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html)*) :

[image]